# Can an Intel 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection be spoofed?

Tags: networking, drivers, mac-address, ubuntu-12.04, spoofing

I need to tell someone my MAC address imminently so I can be added to their router, but I am not at my computer. My laptop is a Dell Latitude E6510, running Ubuntu 12.04 with an Intel 82577LM ethernet card. Can an Intel 82577LM adapter using the standard Ubuntu driver be spoofed without downloading any extra software? I obviously won't have internet access without having first done this.

I know how to spoof a MAC address in Ubuntu, but as mentioned in the [ifconfig man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/ifconfig.8.html), this only works if the device driver supports it.

```
#ifconfig eth0 down 
#ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:80:48:BA:d1:30
#ifconfig eth0 up
```

Is there some way I can know in advance if this will work?

Comment: According to it's [datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ethernet-controllers/82577-gbe-phy-datasheet.html) the 82577LM supports MacSec which prevents MAC spoofing in the presence of appropriate hardware. The question becomes whether Ubuntu supports MacSec in 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I asked on the [e1000e driver](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=15817) (the Linux driver used for Intel® 82563/6/7, 82571/2/3/4/7/8/9, 82583, and i217 controllers) mailing list as mentioned in the docs and I was told:

> For the 82577LM device, e1000e does support MAC spoofing but not MACSec.

By Bruce W Allan, one of the [authors](http://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/wiki/Home/) of the driver.

The e1000e project can be found on sourceforge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/).